# UWP GridView Collapsing the First item also collapse the others items

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp

I have a problem with showing the items in a Gridview. Gridview has a default property,first item's height affects the height of other items. In my code I have used a collection view source to group the items.Each group name has a button to expand or collapse its contents. When the first item is collapsed the other items get collapsed too. but,I want only the particular group that is tapped to be collapsed.

Collection View Source

```
 <CollectionViewSource IsSourceGrouped="True" x:Key="UsersSource" 
                              Source="{x:Bind GetProjectUsersVM.UsersGroup,Mode=OneWay}"
                              x:Name="UsersSource"></CollectionViewSource>
```

Grid View

```
<GridView  Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="UsersList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind UsersSource.View,Mode=OneWay}"
                       IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None"   >
            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle >
                   <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"></VariableSizedWrapGrid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>

                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="usersModel:UsersGroup">
                           
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="auto" Margin="7,0,0,0" Tapped="Expandersymbol_Tapped" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind GroupName,Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="DimGray" Margin="10" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE0E5;" Name="Expandersymbol" 
                                           FontSize="9" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Margin="-5,17,0,0"
                                           Tag="{x:Bind GroupName,Mode=OneWay}"  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                               
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </GridView.GroupStyle>

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

           
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="users:UserDetail"  >

                    <StackPanel BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Row="1" 
                           Height="auto" Width="250" Visibility="{x:Bind IsVisibility,Mode=OneWay}"
                            >

                      <!-- USERS DETAILS-->
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>

            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
  private void Expandersymbol_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
            TextBlock textblock = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(stackPanel,1) as TextBlock;
            var Tag = textblock.Tag;
            string Groupname = Tag.ToString();
            if (textblock.Text == "\uE0E5")
            {
                textblock.Text = "\uE097";

            //GetProjectUsersVM.ProjectUsers contains the usersdetails
            
             foreach (UserDetail Uservisibility in 
                                     GetProjectUsersVM.ProjectUsers)
             {   
 
             //Roles are used to Group a Users
             //PortalProjectUserAndProfileRelationship.RoleOrPortalRoleName contains a rolename of the particular user
              
               if(Uservisibility.
PortalProjectUserAndProfileRelationship.RoleOrPortalRoleName == Groupname)
               {
                                    
                 Uservisibility.IsVisibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
                                   

                 }
                }
             }
            else
            {
            textblock.Text = "\uE0E5";
            foreach (UserDetail Uservisibility in GetProjectUsersVM.ProjectUsers)
            {
            if (Uservisibility.
PortalProjectUserAndProfileRelationship.RoleOrPortalRoleName == Groupname)
              {

                  Uservisibility.IsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

               }
             }
             }
}
```

[Model Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaGCq.png)

Comment: Hello, I noticed that in the `HeaderTemplate`, you have attached an `Expandersymbol_Tapped` event. Can you provide the code for this part?

Comment: I added that CodeBehind Now, Please check. @RichardZhang-MSFT

Comment: Hello, you can try to add breakpoints to the positions where `textblock.Text == "\uE0E5"` and `RoleOrPortalRoleName == Groupname` are judged respectively and check in the debugging state to see if it proceeds as expected. Or after judging `RoleOrPortalRoleName == Groupname`, add an `else` to set `Uservisibility.IsVisibility` that is not equal to **Visible**. In fact, I hope you can provide a sample that can reproduce the problem, including the complete definition of your data type, which will help me reproduce your problem.

Comment: i check with breakpoints ,visibility properties are set properly.The issue  belongs to UI behavior(Default  behavior of Grid view items height). @RichardZhang-MSFT

Comment: Hello, can you explain the "highly default behavior", I tried to create a simple demo, and did not reproduce this problem. Can you provide a minimal runnable demo (without private information), it would be very helpful.